# Show matrix function in haskell

Tags: haskell

I've just started learning functional programming with Haskell and I need your help in the case below.

The idea is to display a Matrix using the show function in the following way:

```
> Mat [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
  1 2 3
  4 5 6
```

I already have a suggested solution that achieves the above outcome, but I do not particularly understand it.

```
data Mat a = Mat {mrows :: [[a]]}
instance (Show a) => Show (Mat a) where
     show  =  unlines . map (unwords . map show) . mrows
```

I have searched on the internet regarding this part `Mat {mrows :: [[a]]}` but could not find any helpful answer. Why we can't just declare it as `Mat [[a]]`?

Also, how does exactly the last line achieves the above outcome. My apologies if the answer is too obvious, but I literally just started learning Haskell.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is actually no problem - if you want to you can declare it this way

```
data Mat a = Mat [[a]]
```

then you just have to alter the show instance declaration a bit

```
instance (Show a) => Show (Mat a) where
     show (Mat x) = unlines $ map (unwords . map show) x
```

### Edit

The other approach has a few upsides:

If you want to get a bit more performance you can change the `data` keyword to `newtype`.

Moreover if you want to assert that this list of lists contain only lists of the same size - you can *not* export the constructor `Mat` but provide a 'smart' constructor `mat :: [[a]] -> Maybe (Mat a)` like:

```
mat x = if  (length $ nub $ map length x) <= 1) then Just x else Nothing
```

but with the latter approach you can always still extract the `[[a]]` part if you export `mrows`

```
module Mat (Mat, mrows, mat) where ...
```

would hide the `Mat` construcor, but export the type of `Mat` where

```
module Mat (Mat(..), mat) ...
```

would export everything

### Edit2

AAAAAnother thing - if you have a type with multiple records say

```
data Pirate = Pirate { head :: HeadThing
                     , rightArm :: ArmThing
                     , leftArm :: ArmThing
                     , rightLeg :: LegThing
                     , leftLeg :: LegThing}

data ArmThing = ...
data HeadThing = ...
data LegThing = ...
```

you can update one (or more "members") with record syntax - i.e.

```
redBeard :: Pirate
redBeard = blackbeard {head = RedBeard, rightArm = Hook}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! If it is not a problem, can you explain the difference of the two approaches?

Comment: @JohnStef It would probably be more useful for you to read about data declarations in haskell

Answer (score 2):

```
data Mat a = Mat {mrows :: [[a]]}
```

This is Haskell's "record syntax". (That's the term you want to search for.) The above declaration is identical to

```
data Mat a = Mat [[a]]
```

The difference is that the second one declares a `Mat` constructor with an "unnamed" field of type `[[a]]`, which the first one *names* the field `mrows`. In particular, this auto-defines a function

```
mrows :: Mat a -> [[a]]
```

that "unwraps" the `Mat` constructor. You can also use the name `mrows` in patterns, but that's generally more useful for constructors with *dozens* of fields, not just one.

A named field can always be referred to using unnamed syntax as well, so the named version does everything the unnamed version does plus a bit more.